# How can I build a foldable desk within my window frame?

Tags: technique, tools

I have a small home and wanted a desk preferably which does not touch down in extended position and can be folded into the window bracket. Below is how my window looks like

[image: My Window]

Assuming the width of window is 70 cm. How can I go by building this? The idea that I have is fix a piece of wood (70cm x5cm) on the window with door clamps on it side and attach another piece of wood approx 70cm x 45cm to the door clamps so it opens when pulled down. Then use a belt to hold it up for closing it.

Does that make sense? How can I calculate the wieght it would be able to hold? What are the materials required?

- Wood, what kind?
- Clamps? Hinges? is that the proper name? Would a couple be enough?
- How many hinges/clamps should be used?

I am a complete beginner. If you think I should learn somethings first please direct me. I have gotten so far by spending hours at the hardware store. Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: What is a "door clamp"? I'm having a bit of trouble following your description. How about drawing out what you're envisioning so others can see what you're seeing? Just [edit] your post and include a picture of the drawing. It can be pencil on paper and doesn't have to be to scale, just write in the dimensions.

Comment: *"Does that make sense?"* In short, no. I always advise people not to reinvent the wheel when possible. And with the idea of a fold-up table there is no need to design in a vacuum! I think your simplest bet is to start with an existing design (there are many) and, if necessary, adapt it to your needs... it is possible that you could find a plan that suits your requirements and won't need any major modifications.

Comment: *"I am a complete beginner."* You need some solid groundwork in woodworking to provide a good foundation to proceed from. While YouTube and various woodworking blogs and websites have lots and lots of content the quality varies so much (and some of it is, to be frank, awful) and you won't be able to tell the quality of what you're reading/seeing initially. So I advise beginners to read books as though they are water and you're dying of thirst. You don't have to build a large, expensive, library (or even a large, inexpensive one if you can buy carefully secondhand). [contd]

Comment: Start with your local library/libraries and see what they've got, and also look on Archive.org and in Google books for older material that is now free to read and download everything you like. I have a very extensive library of books on my computer now, that I would not have been able to afford even buying secondhand, and don't have the space for anyway!